# How to pass same instance of a class to another class in typescript?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a class `ChildClass.ts` which has following properties.

```
name: String;
address: String;
```

This class acts as a property in the `MainClass.ts` like this.

```
childClass: ChildClass;
mobNo: String;
```

Now in a component file `A.ts` I am setting the value of `name & address` by first declaring the variable

`@Input chCLass: ChildClass` and instantiating the class in `onInit()`

and then simply doing

```
this.chClass.name = 'FirstName LastName';
```

Now I also have to set the childClass in the MainCLass but I don't want to do it in this component as there are many other UI elements which needs to be filled and only then it will be better to set it into MainClass.

So there is another component file(`B.ts`) in which I want to set this `childClass` into `Mainclass`.

I tried creating the instance of MainClass and declaring childClass in the component but when I set the value like

```
B.ts

cCLass: ChildClass;
mClass: MainClass;

onInit(){
 this.mClass = new MainClass();
}

this.mClass.childClass = this.cCLass;
```

But printing **this.mClass** in console gives empty childClass.

I was under a impression that once the value is set in childClass in `A.ts`, I can simply assign it to MainClass even if MainCLass instance is in B.ts.

I have created a Stackblitz for rough idea.

*the value of Childclass variables is assigned in A.ts and this childClass object needs to be asigned to MainClass in B.ts*

```
stackblitz.com/edit/angular-7-master-xip1sm?file=src/app/B.ts
```

Can anyone help me in figuring out how to set childClass property to MainClass in `B.ts` while the values to childClass is set in `A.ts` ?

Comment: very difficult to understand what you are trying to achieve. Can you perhaps create a stackblitz to clarify your issue?

Comment: @PoulKruijt 
I have created stackblitz for you, though it doesn't work, I hope you will get a rough idea.

I have set the values of childClass in A.ts
and that childClass needs to be assigned to MainClass in B.ts

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-7-master-xip1sm?file=src/app/B.ts

Comment: I'd recommend to actually just fill that in `mainclass.ts` and pass it to the components that should modify certain properties (using two-way-binding). Alternatively you could create a service that holds the class and access that from the components.

Comment: MainClass has many childClass, and all childClass are getting filled from different component classes.
So once I am filling a childClass from a componen and then fill another childClass from another component, I can only see the latest childCLass values if I print MainClass in console.